# WCF : Moving from IIS 7 to IIS 8

Tags: wcf

I have moved my my wcf service from iis7 to 8.i can browse to the svc file but i cannot browse to any other methods through get or post method.it shows the below error

**The sever encountered an error processing the request.see server logs for more details**

**the log file is shown below**

Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-12-17 04:25:48
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-12-17 04:25:48 (ipaddress) GET /service - 786 - (ipaddress) Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 301 0 0 120
2014-12-17 04:25:48 (ipaddress) GET /service/ - 786 - (ipaddress) Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 3
2014-12-17 04:25:53 (ipaddress) GET /service/MposService.svc - 786 - (ipaddress) Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko (ipaddress):786/service/ 200 0 0 904
2014-12-17 04:27:42 (ipaddress) GET /service/MposService.svc - 786 - publicip Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.95+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 628
2014-12-17 04:27:42 (ipaddress) GET /favicon.ico - 786 - public ip Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.95+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 470
**2014-12-17 04:28:24 (ipaddress) GET /service/MposService.svc/getCustomer section=s1 786 - 117.213.26.161 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.95+Safari/537.36 - 400 0 0 640**

Comment: And what did the server logs show you?

Comment: Try running `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Comment: i couldn't find it on server 2012 R2